# unset a variable passed through post in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have ajax code in my javascript file as follows:

```
// Default settings for Ajax requests
        $.ajaxSetup({
            type: 'POST',   
            url: path + '/relay.php'+ '?curr=' + currency + "&ver=" + Math.random(),
            success: function(response) {
                // Refresh the cart display after a successful Ajax request
                container.html(response);
                $('#jcart-buttons').remove();
            },
               .......
```

The above will post as (in firebug):

```
POST http://www.myshop.com/cart/relay.php?curr=EUR&ver=0.5750630930208085
```

I have a remove function as follows:

```
function remove(link) {
        // Get the query string of the link that was clicked
        var queryString = link.attr('href');
        queryString = queryString.split('=');

        // The id of the item to remove
        var removeId = queryString[1];

        // Remove the item and refresh cart display
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                "jcartRemove": removeId,
                "jcartIsCheckout": isCheckout
            }
        });
    }
```

The remove will display as follows(firebug)

```
GET http://www.myshop.com/cart/relay.php?curr=EUR&ver=0.5750630&jcartRemove=5
```

I need to remove the curr variable too...

How can i do it in my remove link code above ???

Comment: if you want to remove it, why are you adding it in the first place? wouldn't it just be easier to **NOT** put it into your `relay.php` script to start with?

Comment: @Marc B I need to pass the curr variable to another page..

Answer (score 0):

CHANGE AJAX METHOD BECAUSE YOU ARE SENDING PARAMETERS FROM URL **(this is get method to send parameters)**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        type: 'GET',   
        url: path + '/relay.php'+ '?curr=' + currency + "&ver=" + Math.random(),
        success: function(response) {
            // Refresh the cart display after a successful Ajax request
            container.html(response);
            $('#jcart-buttons').remove();
        },
```

---

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "jcartRemove": removeId,
            "jcartIsCheckout": isCheckout
        }
    });
```

HERE ARE THE LINKS:

> [**LINK AJAX**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)
>
> ---
>
> [**LINK POST**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)
>
> ---
>
> [**LINK GET**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Sorry The code you provided is not working. The remove link stops working

Comment: I showed you how to use ajax ... please overview your code and write a  error from command

Comment: My question was what changes do i need to make in my // Remove the item and refresh cart display function above.

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to change the $.ajaxSetup method, the url used in this method i.e
    url: path + '/relay.php'+ '?curr=' + currency + "&ver=" + Math.random()
contains curr and ver parameters but you don't need curr variable in Remove Function So you need to remove curr varible from this url and add curr variable only in particular ajax calls where it will be required.

2.Like by default your url should be
url: path + '/relay.php?ver=' + Math.random()

and add curr varible in your subsequent ajax calls using data parameter.

3.Now, when you call remove function default query string will not contain curr parameter.

```
function remove(link) {
        // Get the query string of the link that was clicked
        var queryString = link.attr('href');
        queryString = queryString.split('=');

        // The id of the item to remove
        var removeId = queryString[1];

        // Remove the item and refresh cart display
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                "jcartRemove": removeId,
                "jcartIsCheckout": isCheckout
            }
        });
    }
```

GET http://www.myshop.com/cart/relay.php?ver=0.5750630&jcartRemove=5&jcartIsCheckout=true
in case isCheckout=true
GET http://www.myshop.com/cart/relay.php?ver=0.5750630&jcartRemove=5&jcartIsCheckout=false
in case isCheckout=false

In case you have any queries, do post.

Comment: Sorry..I don't understand your answer

Comment: I need to remove the curr variable previously added and currently in query string. While splitting how can i go about it ??